# Reading value after Interlocked.CompareExchange()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Suppose I have some base class

```
public abstract class ReflectionSupport
{
    private const int UnresolvedFieldsFlag = -1;
    private const int TrueFieldsFlag = 1;
    private const int FalseFieldsFlag = 0;

    // flag holder
    private int _flagHasFields = UnresolvedFieldsFlag;

    // variant 1 
    protected bool HasFields
    {
       get
       {
          Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _flagHasFields, ResolveHasFieldsFlag(), UnresolvedFieldsFlag);
          return (TrueFieldsFlag == Volatile.Read(ref _flagHasFields));
       }
    }

    // variant 2
    protected bool HasFields
    {
         get
         {
             Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _flagHasFields, ResolveHasFieldsFlag(), UnresolvedFieldsFlag);
             return (TrueFieldsFlag == _flagHasFields);
         }
    }

    private int ResolveHasFieldsFlag()
    { 
         // here reflection is used 
         // to analyze current instance 
         // and returns TRUE-flag if instance 
         // contains field
    }
}
```

My question - what variant **HasFields** property I should use after **Interlocked.CompareExchange()**. Is the value of flag stored in field is the latest one after Interlocked operation or I will have to use volatile read?

Comment: Your question seems unclear. CompareExchange returns the previous value as the result, if that helps. Why would you need to read the value that you just set?

Comment: That's the thing. I do not need previous value as it by default has value of [UnresolvedFieldsFlag]. I need the just-assigned value of the field [_flagHasFields]. I need the most recent assigned value as a result whether a class has internal fields, a function result

Comment: Why don't you just check the value of `ResolveHasFieldsFlag()` ? Why do you think you need `CompareExchange` here?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. This property [HasFields] is used in multi-thread environment and the function [ResolveHasFieldsFlag] is very heavy and should be executed ONLY ONCE, after that its result will be stored in the field [_flagHasFields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info of your comment, you can just use `Lazy` in the following way

```
public abstract class ReflectionSupport
{
    private readonly Lazy<bool> _hasFields;
    protected bool HasFields => _hasFields.Value;

    protected ReflectionSupport()
    {
        _hasFields = new Lazy<bool>(HasFieldsFlag);
    }

    private bool HasFieldsFlag()
    { 
        // just return true if instance 
        // contains field
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no more need in `UnresolvedFieldsFlag`, so `bool` can be used instead

Comment: Thanks, yesterday I implemented with Lazy